# Problem with Euclidean distance in ArcGIS

Tags: raster, arcmap, suitability-analysis

[image]

In ArcGIS 10.7.1, when I run the Euclidean distance it completes but the result is blank and doesn't show anything in data view and the distance in table of content is 0.

When running the Euclidean tool the environment setting were:
Extend: as default
Coordinate system: same as the layer

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: What were the inputs?

Comment: Your inputs are in geographic coordinate system, project them.

Comment: Thanks changed the projection system and it is working